# how to solve equation when logarithms are involved

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation I need to solve:
$$\ln(y)=a\ln(x)+b$$

I know $\ln(A^n)=n\ln(A)$, but how I solve above equation for y?
Thanks

Comment: Try using $e^{\ln (y)}=y$

Comment: Maybe $\exp(ln(y)) = y$ is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\ln y-\ln x^a=b$$
$$\ln\frac{y}{x^a}=b$$
$$\frac{y}{x^a}=e^b$$
$$y=e^bx^a$$

Answer (score 3):

Taking  both sides as an exponent of e:

$e^{ln(y)}=e^{a\cdot ln(x)+b}$

$y=e^{a\cdot ln(x)+b}$

$y=e^{a\cdot ln(x)}\cdot e^b$

$y=\left( e^{ln(x)} \right)^a\cdot e^b$

$y=x^a\cdot e^b$

Answer (score 1):

Take both sides to the power of $e$. Also note $a\ln{x}=\ln{x^a}$

$$
\begin{align}
\ln(y) &= a\ln(x)+b \\
&= \ln{x^a}+b \\
\end{align}
$$

Now

$$
\begin{align}
  e^{\ln{y}} &= e^{\ln{x^a}+b} \\
  y &= e^{\ln{x^a}} e^b \\
  &= e^b x^a \\
\end{align}
$$